# "My family means everything to me"

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

How would you say "My family means everything to me."? As in there's nothing more important to me than my family. I'm not sure which verb to use in this context. I'm guessing *signifier* wouldn't work here...

Merci d'avance.

Comment: I would probably use *être* : Ma famille est tout pour moi, ma famille me vaut plus que toute autre chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ma famille est tout ce qui importe dans ma vie.

Ma famille est le centre et seul intérêt de ma vie.

Ma famille c'est tout ce qui donne du sens à ma vie.

Ma famille c'est ma vie !

Answer (score 3):

You could use the verb "représenter".

> Ma famille représente tout pour moi.

That sounds natural.

Answer (score 1):

> (Le bonheur de) ma famille, **c'est ce qu'il y a de plus important**.
>
> **Tout ce qui compte pour moi**, c'est (le bonheur de) ma famille.